# find an object In a list base on other object

Tags: c#

I have a list that contains many objects.I want found an object in this list that every properties equals to an object in list.
for example:

```
list.Add(object1,object2,object3,object4);
// for example I want found object3
//list.find(object3)
```

and I have a problem I must check every its properties except one. for example object have this properties (int prop1,int prop2,int prop3). I want found object that prop1 and prop2 are equaled with any item of list;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the Equals method would be a way to go.

Or you can try to write a find function use reflection to dynamically check the properties of those Objects.

Please check the article here: http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2007/08/03/use-reflection-to-compare-the-properties-of-two-objects/

Comment: I should not use for or any loop to implement equal or find function. If i override or write any method i must use loop. thank you for your attention. sincerely you M.Bagheri

Answer (score 1):

So, seems you like to get the Contains-Method of the List to work for you.

Have a look here: [MSDN List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

According to it, you can implement IEquatable in your object to make it happen.

Hope that helps.
Cheers
Sascha

Comment: thank you for your attention and great answer. This is very good Idea for me but when i use this command My code don't call Equals method. I am Using a dynamic variable to my List, may this type causes problem.

Comment: the Contains-Method will call that method automatically to check if the object is already in the list. Did you set a breakpoint in your Equals and see if it was called ?

Comment: dynamics are not that easy to handle with Equals. With type object there is no problem doing something like this: 
    public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            var pi = other.GetType().GetProperty("Test");
            var value = pi.GetValue(other, null);

            return (value.ToString() == Test);
        }

Answer (score 0):

There's always the [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) way of doing things. For example:

```
var haystack = new List<Tuple<int, bool, string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<int, bool, string>(1, true, "one"),
            new Tuple<int, bool, string>(2, false, "two"),
            new Tuple<int, bool, string>(3, true, "three"),
            new Tuple<int, bool, string>(4, true, "four")
        };

var needle = new Tuple<int, bool, string>(3, true, "three");
var found =
    haystack.FirstOrDefault(
        t => t.Item1 == needle.Item1 && t.Item2 == needle.Item2 && t.Item3 == needle.Item3);
Assert.AreSame(haystack[2], found);
```

The `Assert.AreSame` test passes when I run this.